# Yii CDbCriteria select with AS alias

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm joining `page_content` table with the same and after that both have column named `sef_url`
Following code returns an error.
Is there any possibility to get the AS 'alias_name' use inside of `CDbCriteria->select`

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 'p';
$criteria->select = array('p.sef_url, p.date_last_modified, pc.sef_url AS parent_sef_url');
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN page_content pc ON p.parent_pageid = pc.pageid';

$criteria->condition = 'p.published=:published AND p.sitemap_index=:sitemap_index';
$criteria->params = array(':published'=>1,':sitemap_index'=>0); 

$result_arr = parent::model()->findAll($criteria);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_arr);

foreach($result_arr as $row) {
  echo $row['parent_sef_url'];
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Try defining public $parent_sef_url in your page_content model. I guess it's similar to http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7118-select-as-newcolumn-with-cdbcriteria/

Comment: My error is, this is an invalid code `$criteria->select=array(..., pc.sef_url AS parent_sef_url');` However I need a way to uniquely identify these two `sef_url` columns

Answer (score 0):

Also you should define a relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'parentPageContent'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PageItem', 'parent_pageid'),
    );
}
```

After you can do that:

```
$pageContents = PageContent::model()->with('parentPageContent')->findAllByAttributes(array(':published'=>1,':sitemap_index'=>0));
foreach($pageContents as $pageContent){
    echo $pageContent->parentPageContent->sef_url;
}
```